# django not returning appropriate response

Tags: python, django

I have a template with checkbox and a button. I want , when i select all checkbox and press the button it should return the values and display it as a httpresponse.

Index.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/test/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="row-1">
        <button name="pack" id="pack">Pack</button>
    </div>
    <div id="row-2">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this, 'no')"></th>
                    <th>Order Id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="no" value="10000001">10000001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="no" value="10000002">10000002</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from test1 import forms

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def pack(request):
    oid_list = []
    form = forms.PackOrders(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for item in form.cleaned_data['no']:
            oid_list.append(item)
    return HttpResponse(','.join(oid_list))
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
from test1 import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^test/', views.pack, name='pack'),)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class PackOrders(forms.Form):
    order_items = forms.CharField()
```

The problem is that when i cleck the checkbox and i return the code it just reload the index.html instead of displaying the values of checkbox.

Expected Output:

```
10000001,10000002
```

What is wrong with the code?

EDIT :

projects urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('test1.urls')),
    url(r'^test/', include('test1.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Do you get a single comma (`,`) if you visit `/test/` in your browser?

Comment: no, it just redisplay the index,html even when i go to `localhost:8000/test`

Comment: Hmm. It should show an error (you have a slash in your url pattern but not in your example). Are you sure you are using the urlpatterns you posted? Have you restarted Django since you last changed your urlpatterns?

Comment: I posted the urls i am using and yes i restarted server several times. But same problem every time

Comment: Is this your root URLconf? If not, please post that. And also what happens if you change the `action` of your form to `"{% url "test" %}"`?

Comment: On changing `\test\` to `"{% url 'test' %}"` I get this error `Reverse for 'test' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` on line with `action` in index.html. And this a application in my django project and urls.py is for that application.

Comment: @ManishGupta - it needs to be `{% url 'pack' %}`

Comment: Yes, but what is the *root* URL conf? It seems like you are not actually including this file properly. (And yes, Sayse is right, it should have been "pack", not "test".)

Comment: i included the projects URLconf. I wasn't able to pinpoint the source of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've included your app urlconf into your root urlconf twice. You should only do it once. However, you should remove the $ from the URL that includes it:

```
url(r'^', include('test1.urls')),
```

If you used the second version instead, with the 'test/' prefix, you would create URLs at '/test/' and '/test/test/', which presumably isn't what you want.

Note though that as I said in the comment, you should always reference URLs via their name, not directly. So your form action should be `"{% url 'pack' %}"`.

Comment: Now it is throwing `'PackOrders' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`. I get it has to with `views.py`. In several posts here on SO they used this attribute to get form data. So why it is throwing error? Am i using it in wrong way?

Comment: @ManishGupta - Its probably because the form isn't valid (check with `form.is_valid()`), which it won't be because you haven't provided a value for the order_items and I don't know what relevance the checkboxes have in that form. But thats an entirely different question outside of the scope of the one you have asked.

Comment: I have provided value for the checkbox in html. And `is_valid()` is throwing False. Also This is a test project the real project included the data to be passed as a parametre to a python script. So how can i correct the value. I just want to print the value of checkboxes in a html page.

Comment: You should ask a new question about this. But there doesn't seem to be any reason you are using a form here at all, rather than just accessing request.POST.

Answer (score 0):

`$` in regex indicates the end of the string so your include will never get chance to match any of its urls (which I imagine is what your other urls.py is). Therefore you need to change your urls to the included urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/', include('test1.urls')),
    url(r'^test/', include('test1.urls')),
]
```

Notice I have changed the second one to remove the `$` and replace it with a slash