# django return same page on clicking button

Tags: python, django

Hi I have a html with a form and a button like:

```
<form action="{% url 'packOrders' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button name="pack_orders" id="pack_orders" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa">Pack Orders</button>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this, 'no')"></th>
                <th>Invoice</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Order date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Tracking Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for oid,dbd,stts,tp in new_orders %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="no" value="{{oid}}"></td>
                <td><a class="btn-link" href="#">{{oid}}</a></td>
                <td>Steve N. Horton</td>
                <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{dbd}}</span></td>
                <td>{{tp}}</td>
                <td>{{stts}}</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
from orders import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                    url(r'^$', views.orders, name='orders'),
                    url(r'^test/', views.packOrders, name='packOrders'),)
```

Views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from orders import forms


def orders(request):
    return render(request, 'orders/orders.html', context_dict)


def packOrders(request):
    oid_list = []
    form = forms.PackOrders(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print form.is_valid()
        list_of_ids = request.POST.getlist('no')
        for id in list_of_ids:
            oid_list.append(id)
    return HttpResponse(','.join(oid_list))
```

Currently In `orders.html` page, when i select checkboxes and press the button it goes to `orders.html/test` and prints the item from list. I want when i click button `Pack Orders`, It just reroute to the `orders.html` or to say refresh it with current values. There is a backend script which works on the item list so i will just call a method in `packOrders` Method.

NOTE: I didn't write the code in `orders` method in views.py which displays the data in `orders.html`.

How to reroute it in urls.py? I tried several solutions including HttpResponseRedirect and may but didn't worked.

EDIT :

projects urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^login.html/', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^index.html/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    url(r'^orders.html/', include('orders.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Well, write the code in `orders` view. What's the problem?

Comment: I thought that's not relevnt to question. the code just get data from models.py and pass data as `context_dict` to html.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32374427/1324033)? In that one you had two identical url paths that lead to different places

Comment: No. That question was about how to pass values from html template to views.py. This one is about page redirect. The code is same but questions are different.

Comment: But its the code thats the problem, can you update your question with your  root urls.py as they currently are?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Is `packOrders` view saving somewhere received data? If yes, where? If no - what you want to do with that data?

Comment: @GwynBleidD As i said in question there is python script which updates data on server. The data recieved in post is passed as a parametre to that script's method. I will call the method from my view later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


def packOrders(request):
    # your code
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders'))
```

That will be simplest solution. Also, you can simply "pack" your code into one view, use some JavaScript or just render your data again in packOrders view.

But recommended way is to use Redirects always after post method - that way user won't be able to sent data again when refreshing page.

Also, you can use FormView:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class PackOrdersView(FormView):
    form_class = PackOrders

    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders') # we can't use normal reverse here, because it will be evaluated before urlconf is parsed

    def form_valid(self, form):

        # your code here

        return super(PackOrdersView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Class based views are more flexible and can do lot of work for you, so you don't have to handle forms, objects creation etc by yourself.

Comment: And How to use urls.py with HttpresponseRedirect. I used HttpResponseRedirect, But it formed a url like: `../orders.html/test/test...`

Comment: How did you use it and what do you mean by 'use urls.py with HttpResponseRedirect'?